# Aligning button and link in a div, broken in IE, works in FF

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I know this has been asked before, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I am trying to vertically align a button and a link in a div. Both the button and the link should be on the same line centered vertically with each other.  It works in FireFox but not in IE7 or IE8.

Html:

```
<div class="submitform">   
    <input type="submit" value="Initiate Request" />  
    <a href="/test2">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.submitform a 
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.submitform
{
    width: 600px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

This is what it looks like in IE7 and 8:

[image]

Note that the Cancel link is not vertically aligned in the middle with the button. It is aligned correctly in FireFox.

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Here are the inherited styles:

[image]

How can I fix the alignment?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to fix rendering problems specific to IE7, the following reference may be useful: http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight.html deals specifically with how IE7 handles line height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your CSS to this:

```
.submitform {
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
}

.submitform input, .submitform a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.submitform a {
    padding-left: 10px;  line-height: 30px;
}
```

The key changes here are:

1. Moved `vertical-align: middle` from parent to children elements.
2. Applied `line-height: 30px` to anchor tag.
3. Removed `padding-top: 15px` from parent. If you need padding, increase the height instead.

This works cross-browser and supports IE7 (untested in IE6). This will break if text overflows to two lines.

[See live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsMxW/1/).

Comment: Adding line-height to "submitform a" did not change anything. I also tried adding to to both "submitform a" and "submitform."

Comment: That's too bad. My client is on IE7. :(

Comment: @rboarman I updated my answer and it now works in IE7. You can test it with my jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gsMxW/1/

Comment: Applying vertical-align:middle to the children did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a BREAK and pad the container instead of the link:

```
<div class="submitform">   
    <input type="submit" value="Initiate Request" />  
    <br /><a href="/test2">Cancel</a>
</div>



.submitform
{
    width: 600px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my post wasn't clear enough. I need both elements on the same line centered vertically. In the image above, the cancel link needs to be bumped up a few pixels. I updated my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.submitform a 
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You should be good with IE7/8. Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/Duydm/2/

Comment: Perhaps my post wasn't clear enough. I need both elements on the same line centered vertically. In the image above, the cancel link needs to be bumped up a few pixels. I updated my post. Sorry.

Comment: Your cancel link is bottom aligned in IE7. That is what I am trying to fix! :)

Comment: Sounds like a conditional comment for IE7 and bottom padding for your anchor element. It does work in IE8 and Firefox 3.

Answer (score 0):

Moses is on the right track, you need to adjust the line-height on both the `input` and the `a` elements as shown http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/R8jZj/

Also, be sure to use a **strict doctype** so that you don't have quirks mode effects in IE.

Comment: Your fiddle example is broken in the same way. I am using "-"//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" for my doctype.

Comment: At least Moses and I are consistent! What browser, version and os are you viewing the site/fiddles on?

Comment: Also, what is the default text size setting that you are using?

Comment: You should only use the line-height fix for single-line text; doing so for other elements (like an input) can cause undesirable effects. For example: in IE7 the entire input button would expand to fit the line-height and you would end up with a 50px tall button with 10px tall text inside it.

Comment: @Moses You make a good point, I did not see that effect in IE8 or FF, but I did not check IE7.  I appreciate the heads up.